# How not to capture passwords when writing a keylogger in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I've been tasked with writing employee monitoring application in C# for my company.

Among other things the application might have to contain a keylogger, which isn't necessarily that hard to implement, what i really want to know if there's anyway for it **not to capture** passwords as we have no use for them and i don't really want them in the system.

I'm not looking for code or anything like that, i'm just looking for a way to **not capture** passwords.

Thank you.

Comment: Valid question, but what a loathesome task to be assigned... I pity you

Comment: Creation of (effectively) spyware...not to judge, but I'd personally consider a career change at that point.  Also I'd be careful with other personal information you might be tracking (for example, if someone enters a credit card number to buy something online, you're now responsible for securing that data to make sure it doesn't get somehow leaked out).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this would be legal. If there is any way to achieve this, I think it's gonna be painfull. Career change sounds like an attractive alternative.

Comment: @LorentzVedeler and anyone else that's supprised, i really don't get why people are so surprised a quick google search returned this http://employee-monitoring-software-review.toptenreviews.com/ have a look at the specifications i'm just trying to do something different

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if it is possible.

For a key logger, any key pressed will matter, there are so many places where a user could enter a password, I don't think you can cover all the cases to differentiate between them.

Also, you should consider using [existing](http://www.technicalinfo.net/blog/security/20071230_CommercialKeylogger.html) solutions, instead of developing your own.

Comment: I know that any key press matters, but from what i remember years ago when i was playing with one it had a system that highlighted password that same system can be used to skip that entry, i just don't know how it was implemented

Answer (score 0):

If you evaluate the software you might be able to determine if it was password box.
e.g. in html   input type="password"

I suspect for domain login you could do something similar.
Or just not have the logger start until they are logged in.